# Connect to a website with username and password and retrieve source code in Windows Phone 7 (C#)?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've done this already with android. Now I'm trying to do it in Windows Phone 7. What is the equivalent of this code in c#? I also want to save the source code in a string.

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://students.usls.edu.ph/login.cfm");

username = txtUname.getText().toString();
password = txtPass.getText().toString();

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Answer (score 0):

You set credentials like this:

```
WebClient httpclient = new WebClient();

username = txtUname.Text;
password = txtPass.Text;

httpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

Where txtUname and txtPass are TextBox elements.

In order to POST, it's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp).

Comment: how can I retrieve the source code of the website to check that I was able to login?

Comment: Download string asynchronously. Check out this tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/webclient

Comment: I was able to download the source code but the source code it downloads is of the login screen. I want to download the source code of the next page. How can I do it?