# Can't GET my application's app page (100)

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

My application has 3 pages associated with it. Here are their id's :

- 151500351683665 (Community page)
- 143448712494935 (Community page)
- 563925353640654 (Application page)

Using the facebook C# SDK, I'm trying to execute GET on those pages using the following url format :

```
graph.facebook.com/{pageId}
```

- http://graph.facebook.com/563925353640654 -> Error
- http://graph.facebook.com/143448712494935 -> Ok
- http://graph.facebook.com/151500351683665 -> Ok

I'm successful when it comes to the community pages, however I'm getting a Unsupported GET request (100) when trying to access the Application page in this manner. I'm not sure what's going on this started to occur recently, the whole thing worked without passing any access tokens as I thought that this was public information :/

Any ideas?

Note: Until lately I was able make the forementioned GET requests without any access tokens - since I believe I was accessing public information. Right only unable to access a single page.

Comment: Are you talking about `Expect100Continue` error?
[Try this one then](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341287/expect-100-continue)

Comment: This is probably more relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api

Comment: Same error as Kloar is describing, oddly it started to occur only recently

Comment: @user207205 is this even facebook-related?

Comment: Apparently it might be a bug : https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/501013603286063?browse=search_5178c96ad3ee64900580194

Answer (score 0):

Copying the answer from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13739609/unsupported-get-request-in-facebook-graph-api)

```
This error occures due to several problems in the permissions of your page

1. Go to edit page->manage permission

Check Age restrictions: 13+

2. Go to basic information -> Start Type:: set to launched
```

Comment: Completed steps 1 and 2, waited a few mins for the change to propagate to Fb's servers - still getting the error.

Comment: Interestingly this works when I access it from the Graph API explorer, as my application - the token is weird though, I'm unable to generate the same token in code :/

Comment: Another observation I've made : I can access the page using my access token (I'm 21+ etc.), however I can't access the page using a test user's access token. This isn't the case with the other pages though