# Visual studio 2010 c# form post data to php page using geckoWebBrowser?

Tags: c#, php, visual-studio-2010, geckofx

i was wondering how to post data from c# form to a php using geckoWebBrowser?
I have done it with IE browser on form

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        String postdata = "data=somedata";

        System.Text.Encoding a = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        byte[] byte1 = a.GetBytes(postdata);

        webBrowser1.Navigate("somepage.php", "", byte1, "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    }
```

But how to do it with geckoWebBrowser1.Navigate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [`GeckoWebBrowser.Navigate()`](http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/source/browse/trunk/Skybound.Gecko/GeckoWebBrowser.cs?r=2) passes its parameters to a [`nsIWebNavigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebNavigation) instance, which is the [`XPCOM`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPCOM) interface for running a browser instance, in this case using [`XULRunner 1.8`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XULRunner_1.8.0.1_Release_Notes) (which is pretty old).

Unfortunately, the `Navigate()` method of the `GeckoWebBrowser` does not supply an overload for `postData`; it simply passes `Intptr.Zero` for that argument.

I can't test it, but if you create a new method like this in `GeckoWebBrowser.cs`, you can call it with a string containing post data:

```
public bool Navigate(string url, string postData, GeckoLoadFlags loadFlags)
{
    if (url == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
    }

    if (!IsHandleCreated)
    {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cannot call Navigate() before the window handle is created.");
    }

    if (IsBusy)
    {
        this.Stop();
    }

    return WebNav.LoadURI(url, (uint)loadFlags, null, GetStreamFromString(postData), IntPtr.Zero) == 0;
}

public static Stream??? CreateStreamFromString(string input)
{
    return new StreamReader???(input);
}
```

Please note that the `LoadURI` method accepts an [`nsIInputStream`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIInputStream) parameter, which I do not know. Try to find the parameter type and how to instantiate that, and fix the `CreateStreamFromString()` method to return and instantiate the right type.

Also check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWebNavigation#loadURI%28%29) for the `postData` parameter:

> If the URI corresponds to a HTTP request, then this stream is appended directly to the HTTP request headers. It may be prefixed with additional HTTP headers. This stream must contain a \r\n sequence separating any HTTP headers from the HTTP request body. This parameter may be null.

---

But perhaps you just want to use a [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) (.NET 4.5 only) class if this is only for posting data to some URL.

Comment: Only problem is that i am newby to c#, can you please tell me how to post simple data like on my example with ie (data=somedata)
Here is my code [link](http://jna.info.tm/help.txt)

Comment: @DraganGJankovic no, I can't write code for you. Why do you want to use a web browser control? If that isn't required, take a look at a [`WebClient` example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp).