# ASP.NET MVC curl equivalent

Tags: curl, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble finding much details on this. I need to work with an api that processes credit cards and it uses curl. All documentation is in php and while I could use php my main site is entirely in MVC4 using razor view engine. I need to convert this wich is from php to something useable in .net

```
$ curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers -u *private key here*: 
       -d "description=Customer for test@example.com" -d "card[number]=4242424242424242" 
       -d "card[exp_month]=12" -d "card[exp_year]=2013"
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: you can use the `System.Web.WebClient` object to perform that

Comment: What do the `-u` and `-d` options do?  Are they just query string / post data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from the [curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) page

- `-u, --user <user:password>` is the User credentials
- `-d, --data <data>` is the POST data

so you can "decode" this as:

```
using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    // data
    string parameters = string.Concat("description=", description, "&amp;card[number]=" , cardNumber, "&amp;card[exp_month]=", cardExpirationMonth, "&amp;card[exp_year]=", cardExpirationYear),
           url = "https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers;

    // let's fake it and make it was a browser requesting the data
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");

    // credentials
    wc.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*private key here*", "");

    // make it a POST instead of a GET
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    // send and get answer in a string
    string result = wc.UploadString(url, parameters);
}
```

---

updated with POST tweak from an [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401597/28004).