# C# using REST API POST parameter as array

Tags: c#, php, http, rest, post

I need to create the following PHP POST in C#

```
$params = array(    
'method' => 'method1',   
'params' => array 
    (    
        'P1' => FOO,    
        'P2' => $Bar, 
        'P3' => $Foo,
    ) 
);
```

I cannot figure out how to create the `params` array. I have tried with `WebClient.UploadString()` with a json string to no avail.

How do I construct the above in C# ?

I try

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        return client.UploadString(EndPoint, "?method=payment");
    }
```

The above works but needs further parameters.

```
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {            
        return client.UploadString(EndPoint, "?method=foo&P1=bar");
    }
```

`P1` is not recognised.

I've tried with `UploadValues()` but cannot store the params in a `NamedValueCollection`

The API is https://secure-test.be2bill.com/front/service/rest/process

Comment: What API are you calling? It would be cool to read the docs if possible.

Comment: https://secure-test.be2bill.com/front/service/rest/process

Comment: What's with the downvotes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like explained here: http://www.codingvision.net/networking/c-sending-data-using-get-or-post/

it should work like this:

```
string urlAddress = "http://www.yoursite.tld/somepage.php?method=foo&P1=bar1&P2=bar2&P3=bar3";  

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
       string response = client.DownloadString(urlAddress);
}
```

ob maybe you want to use post method... look at the link

in your example for

```
$php_get_vars = array(    
'method' => 'foo',   
'params' => array 
    (    
        'P1' => 'bar1',    
        'P2' => 'bar2', 
        'P3' => 'bar3',
    ) 
);
```

it should be:

```
string urlAddress = "http://www.yoursite.tld/somepage.php?method=foo&params[P1]=bar1&params[P2]=bar2&params[P3]=bar3";
```

Comment: the parameters inside the array, 'P1', etc are not recognised.

Comment: hmm, its not an array in example, it should be $_GET['P1'] in php

Comment: method=foo&params[P1]=bar1&params[P2]=bar2&params[P3]=bar3 worked

Comment: Is there a .NET library that will create such a querystring?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need use the POST method to post data. Many times the error is that you did not set correct request headers.

Here is a solution that should work (first posted by Robin Van Persi in [How to post data to specific URL using WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)):

```
string URI = "http://www.domain.com/restservice.php";
string params = "method=foo&P1=" + value1 + "&P2=" + value2 + "&P3=" + value3;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, params);
}
```

If this does not solve your problem, try more solutions in the answers in link above.

Comment: the parameters inside the array, 'P1', etc are not recognised.