# c# sending data to php url

Tags: c#, php, postdata

okay so I have a c# console source code I have created but it does not work how I want it to.

I need to post data to a URL the same as if I was going to input it an a browser.

```
url with data = localhost/test.php?DGURL=DGURL&DGUSER=DGUSER&DGPASS=DGPASS
```

Here is my c# script that does not do it the way I want to I want it to post the data as if I had typed it like above.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
        string URL = "http://localhost/test.php";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

        NameValueCollection formData = new NameValueCollection();
        formData["DGURL"] = "DGURL";
        formData["DGUSER"] = "DGUSER";
        formData["DGPASS"] = "DGPASS";

        byte[] responseBytes = webClient.UploadValues(URL, "POST", formData);
        string responsefromserver = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
        Console.WriteLine(responsefromserver);
        webClient.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

I have also triead another method in c# this does now work either

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string URI = "http://localhost/test.php";
            string myParameters = "DGURL=value1&DGUSER=value2&DGPASS=value3";

            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "text/html";
                string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, myParameters);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500000000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have been trying to figure a way to do this in my c# console for days now

Comment: What is the problem? What happens?

Comment: I have a php script that waits for the url post and then adds the data to MySQL if I manualy visit the url the data adds but it does not add when I run this code

Comment: I hit the caps by mistake no yelling here

Comment: WE LIKE TO YELL. But seriously, your sample url at the top uses querystrings and later on you pass your values as post parameters, which way do you want it?

Comment: I want to be able to use query string because my php is setup to process it that way

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I want to be able to use query string because my php is setup to process it that way

Comment: For a start you're using a post method where inside the url thats a get method, just switch it to get.

Answer (score 3):

Since what you seem to want is a GET-request with querystrings and not a POST you should do it like this instead.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var dgurl = "DGURL", user="DGUSER", pass="DGPASS";
    var url = string.Format("http://localhost/test.php?DGURL={0}&DGUSER={1}&DGPASS=DGPASS", dgurl, user, pass);
    using(var webClient = new WebClient()) 
    {
        var response = webClient.DownloadString(url);
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}
```

I also wrapped your `WebClient` in a `using`-statement so you don't have to worry about disposing it yourself even if it would throw an exception when downloading the string.

Another thing to think about is that you might want to url-encode the parameters in the querystring using [WebUtility.UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode.aspx) to be sure that it doesn't contain invalid chars.

Answer (score 0):

How to post data to a URL using WebClient in C#: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5401597/2832321

Also note that your parameters will not appear in the URL if you post them. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3477374/2832321

Comment: okay I will have a look and I know that but the data is not being received as MySQL does not get updated

Comment: tried that example above that does nothing either the console does not do anything and I receive no data