# Authentication in wp8

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, windows-phone-8, webclient

I'm developing WP8 application. I need to add data in the url by using the E-mail id and password.  I am using `webclient()`, but I don't know how to do it. Can anyone help me to complete the task?
Thanks in advance.

My URL format:

```
http://xx.xx.xxx.xxx/main/content/api/data/pagename?email=abcd@abcd.com&sig=abcd
```

This is my url structure. I need to add data for the user above.
My Form Design:

```
![enter image description here][1]
```

When I click the log-in button I should verify the emailid and password from the above mentioned url structure.

The code below works for posting the data, but I need to know how to post the data by using email and password.

```
public T Post<T>(string servicePath, string result) 
{ 
    string serviceURL = REST_URI + servicePath; 
    Uri URI = new Uri(serviceURL); 
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); 
    webClient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/json"; 
    webClient.Headers["Accept"] = "application/json"; 
    webClient.UploadStringCompleted += this.sendPostCompleted; 
    webClient.UploadStringAsync(URI, HTTP_POST, result); 
    return default(T); 
}
```

Comment: you have to append after url as per your url format

Comment: sorry i had append it..forget to update..

Comment: i'm getting response from server as "log-in required"

Comment: set content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: sorry it doesn't work..

Comment: set accept type to  application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: do not append parameters as it is POST

Comment: i'm new to WP8 so can you explain it clearly..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp

Comment: i know how to post data,but i need help on to post data by using particular username and password..

Comment: you have to share the data and w/s

Comment: plz check my post.. i had updated..

Comment: what is result string?

Comment: yes.. result contains the string..

Comment: takes emailid and password..

Comment: did u got my description..?

Comment: i had registered the new user.. and that new user need to add/update the data in the url.. by log-in with his/her user name and password... soi need to provide authendication when the user log-in and need to carry the add/update process.. with the login email and password..
my registration code..

Comment: what is the format u need in your POST method

Comment: paste the result string here

Comment: {"email":"abcd@abcd.com", "password": "abcd"}

Comment: if you can paste url??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this , here I'm retrieving username and password from text box,

```
                var username = uname.Text;
                var password = pass.Password;

                var postData = "email=" + username + "&password=" + password;
                WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
                webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                var uri = new Uri("Your URL here", UriKind.Absolute);
                webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
                webClient.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
                webClient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData);
                webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(postComplete);
```