# How to send windows phone 8 application data to server

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have only two input parameters in my feedback form, email, feedback and a submit button only.
I want to send(POST) this data to a specific URL like http://questoons.com/data.php

So how can I post data from windows phone 8 app to a specific URL?

Any code sample or web link would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)'s `UploadStringAsync()` function :

```
string URI = "http://www.myurl.com/post.php";
string myParameters = "param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3";

var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(URI, UriKind.Absolute), myParameters);
```

[[For Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)]

Answer (score 2):

I reccomend to write a specific class for working with POST.

```
public class PostRequestParameters
    {
        public List<PostRequestParameterObject> prms;

        public PostRequestParameters()
        {
            prms = new List<PostRequestParameterObject>();
        }

        public void AddPair(string id, string val)
        {
            prms.Add(new PostRequestParameterObject(id, val));
        }

        public String FormPostData()
        {
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < prms.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    buffer.Append(System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prms[i].id) + "=" + System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prms[i].value));
                }
                else
                {
                    buffer.Append("&" + System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prms[i].id) + "=" + System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(prms[i].value));
                }
            }

            return buffer.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class PostRequestParameterObject
    {
        public string id;
        public string value;

        public PostRequestParameterObject(string id, string val)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.value = val;
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it to send POST data:

```
private void buttonSend_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {               
                WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                wc.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(wc_UploadStringCompleted);
                wc.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

                PostRequestParameters prms = new PostRequestParameters();
                prms.AddPair("par1", textBox1.Text);
                prms.AddPair("par2", textBox2.Text);
                prms.AddPair("par3", GetMPar3());

                wc.UploadStringAsync(new Uri(url), "POST", prms.FormPostData(), null);

        }

        // you can parse response here
        private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // do something
        }
```

Comment: though there is an error in the line starting with "wc.UploadStringCompleted" showing that you need to raise an event since it is an event and cannot be called directly