# Windows phone 8 web browser task

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

```
WebBrowserTask webbrowsertask = new WebBrowserTask();
            webbrowsertask.Uri = new Uri("http://johndoe/index.php?dsa=51",UriKind.Absolute);
            webbrowsertask.Show();
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Mainpage.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

webbrowsertask.Show(); is executing this code and opens browser 
I dont want to open browser , I just want to execute this code(got to this url , because i want this parameters to be sent in my site/database)
are there any other ways ?

Comment: use WebClient then. and remove WebBrowserTask

Comment: Can you give me an example based on this code with WebClient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

String URI = "http://somesite.com/somepage.html";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
Stream stream = webClient.OpenRead(URI);
String request = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

from here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33798/HTTP-GET-with-NET-WebClient

It's raw idea but you can adapt it to whatever you like.

MSDN info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx

P.S. and you definitely need  a `POST` call, rather then `GET`, for storing data in your service/db/whatever, as you mentioned in question.

More info: [How to post data to specific URL using WebClient in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)