# C# not sending POST data to PHP script

Tags: c#, php

So I have a C# script which stores data to a database through my PHP script. My C# script uses `WebClient` to achieve this effect. But sadly my C# script doesn't send `POST` data to my PHP script and I don't know why. This is what I have so far:

### C#

```
json = "{\"bedrijfsNaam\":\"" + bedrijfsNaam + "\"," +
       "\"ContPers\":\"" + ContPers + "\"," +
       "\"TelNum\":\"" + TelNum + "\"," +
       "\"email\":\"" + email + "\"," +
       "\"Land\":\"" + Land + "\"," +
       "\"Plaats\":\"" + Plaats + "\"," +
       "\"PostCode\":\"" + PostCode + "\"}";

var b64bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);
b64encode = System.Convert.ToBase64String(b64bytes);

using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    byte[] sendB64 = client.UploadData("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST",
    System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("b64string=" + b64encode + "&filename=" + dt.bedrijfsNaam));
    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(sendB64));
}
```

### PHP

```
if($link ->connect_errno) 
{
    echo 'ERROR: no connection!';
}
else 
{
    if(isset($_POST['b64string']))
    {
        $jsonstring = base64_decode($_POST['b64string']);

        $obj = json_decode($jsonstring);

        $query_opslaan = "INSERT INTO SalesKicker (BedrijfsNaam, ContPers, TelNr, Email, Land, Plaats, POC) VALUES ('". $obj->bedrijfsNaam ."' , '". $obj->ContPers ."', '". $obj->TelNum ."', '". $obj->email ."', '". $obj->Land ."', '". $obj->Plaats ."', '". $obj->PostCode ."')";         

        mysqli_query($link, $query_opslaan) or die(mysqli_error($query_opslaan));
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'ERROR: no data!';
    }

}
```

The problem is is that my PHP script returns

> "ERROR: no data!"

This should obviously not happen. What should happen is that the PHP gets the `POST` data and saves it to my Database. Can someone please tell me why this isn't working correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure but it looks like you're sending via GET, not POST

Comment: Take a good look at the C# code. It clearly says that it sends data via POST

Comment: Yeah but the way you create the URL, it's GET. When you add variables to the url. Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26143325/4802649) and see if it helps.

Comment: No it's clearly POST, look up MSDN. The code clearly states POST and not GET. GET is not possible with the method I'm using....

Comment: Well, I don't know. Never done this kind of job. But try looking at the answer maybe you find a different approach.

Comment: Well you atleast the question you linked me had the correct answer. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should use the following c# method except of my current one:

```
             var data = new NameValueCollection();
            data["b64string"] = b64encode;
            data["filename"] = dt.bedrijfsNaam;

            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                var uploadData = client.UploadValues("http://" + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scripturi"].ToString() + "SalesKicker.php", "POST",
                data);
                response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(uploadData);
            }
```

I should've been using the NameValueCollection instead of just a string.