# if (isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Number'])) always returns false in PHP

Tags: c#, php, xamarin

```
// xamarin.android c# code 
void mButtonCreateContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomainname.com/abcd.php");
    NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
    parameters.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
    parameters.Add("Number", txtNumber.Text);`
    client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
    client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, parameters);          
}
```

Here I am passing two parameters ater getting input from the user. However in the PHP code it always returns false in the `isset['Name']` function and goes into the `else` statement

```
if (isset($_POST['Name']) && isset($_POST['Number']))
{
    $mName = $_POST['Name'];
    $mNumber = $_POST['Number'];
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
```

Comment: Try using `$_GET` instead of `$_POST` to get the values, if you want to POST instead, try this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/5401597/1870760

Answer (score 1):

You need to set request paramater POST in WebClient.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently sending a `GET` with the values, if you want to use `POST` instead, call it like this:

```
void mButtonCreateContact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.mydomainname.com/abcd.php");
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();
        parameters.Add("Name", txtName.Text);
        parameters.Add("Number", txtNumber.Text);
        client.UploadValuesCompleted += client_UploadValuesCompleted;
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "POST", parameters);          
    }
```

Comment: i made the changes you specified but the result it still the same

Comment: @MudassirDehghani Do you get any when changing `$_POST` to `$_REQUEST` ?

Answer (score 0):

USE to check with `POST`

```
client.UploadValuesAsync(uri, "POST", parameters);
```

Answer (score -1):

Best way is user `$_REQUEST`. WHATEVER YOU USE post or get.