# Submitting html form with hidded fields using code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

heloo,

i have a html form which is posting data to a link like

```
 <body onload="javascript:document.E_FORM.submit();">
    <form  action= method="POST" name="E_FORM">
    <input type="hidden" name="a" value="1" size="100"><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="2"><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="c" value="3"><br /> 
</form>
```

i want to submit this form using code behind using string builder to create form and then submit using WebClient.

Comment: Do you want to submit the form or post values using WebClient? You can refer this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)

Comment: i want to post values, on posting value to action url its redirect to another link i do not need response in my function. just post and that page redirect to another link