# Get response post with no parameters just a submit button

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

So my issue is that I can't seem to get a proper response on this.

Tried using webclient

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // create post parameters
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["pro"] = "";
            // get response
            var response = client.UploadValues("example.com", values);
            l.LoadHtml(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
        }
```

but still no response, I will still only get the form div and not its response

this is how the form I am trying to pass

```
<div id="image">
    <form action="http://example.com" method="POST">
        <p>
            <input class="button white" type="submit" name="img" value="Continue to image ... ">
        </p>
    </form>
</div>
```

not sure how to proceed, thanks for those who can help.

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp

Comment: Nothing works on your related question

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, after so many trial and error I tried putting the input as the paremeter.

```
   using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            // create post parameters
            var values = new NameValueCollection();
            values["img"] = "submit";
            // get response
            var response = client.UploadValues("example.com", values);
            l.LoadHtml(Encoding.Default.GetString(response));
        }
```

You cant post without parameters so if there is only a submit button, thats still a parameter