# How to create a query string that posts data like this "param" : [0.5,0.2,0.02]?

Tags: c#, post, webclient

I want to send data to a server using POST in c# using WebClient method. The data to be send has a key value pair.
key: param
value: [0.5,0.2,0.02]

How to send this kind of data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to post data to specific URL using WebClient in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you tried to do this yourself at all?

Comment: string result = "";
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json"; 
    result = client.UploadString(url, "POST", json);
}
Console.WriteLine(result);

Comment: I have tried all this already. The post data needs to be in [1,2,3] form. So how to make the data appear in the POST url in the first place.

Comment: @viveknuna can you tell me how to write that json part. Will it be in my case something like this: string json="param:[0.5,0.2,0.02]";

Comment: it will be like this {
 "param value": [0.5, 0.2, 0.02]
}

Comment: string postData = "{\"param value\": [0.5, 0.2, 0.02]}";

Comment: ok thanks I will try it and will let you know by tomorrow

Comment: No it's not working.

Comment: Actually I want to send a command to camera whose json string is like this: 
{"method" : "ptz.move", "session" : 2030461149, "params" : {"screen" : [0.5032958984375,0.5662841796875,0.11682510375976562]}, "id" : 83}:"" How to send this. The server is always returning Error 500. It will be better if I can send it directly through url