# MVC website doesn't receive string from client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json.net

Client:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
try
{
    string json = wc.UploadString("http://localhost:50001/Client/Index", "1");
    dynamic receivedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    Console.WriteLine("Result: {0};",receivedData.data);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Oh bother");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Basically sends "1" to the `Index` action in the `Client` controller.

Here is the Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string k)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0};", k));
  return Json(new { data = k}, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

The result from the `Client` is just "Result: ;". The debug output from the controller is also "Result: ;". This means that the data is lost somewhere between the client and the site. But when I debug, Visual Studio says that there was one request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp --Possible Duplicate

Comment: @TKHN Do you think it is because I use UploadString but not UploadData and it should be a byte array?

Comment: @TKHN I tried byte[] but the NullException kiks in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding the header and specifying the parameter name, I've managed to get this to work (in your calling method):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            try
            {
                wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                string json = wc.UploadString("http://localhost:49847/Home/Index", "k=1");
                dynamic receivedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
                Console.WriteLine("Result: {0};", receivedData.data);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Oh bother");
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers(v=vs.110).aspx):

> ...set the HTTP Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded,
>   to notify the server that form data is attached to the post.

I haven't run fiddler to check what (if any) headers are sent through by default but I suspect the reason this doesn't work without the header is the receiving client doesn't know where to find the query string parameters passed through.

From [another answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551194/how-are-parameters-sent-in-an-http-post-request):

> When receiving a POST request, you should always expect a "payload",
>   or, in HTTP terms: a message body. The message body in itself is
>   pretty useless, as there is no standard (as far as I can tell. Maybe
>   application/octet-stream?) format. The body format is defined by the
>   Content-Type header. When using a HTML FORM element with
>   method="POST", this is usually application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

WebAPI may be interpreting your argument as a URI argument.

Try this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([FromBody] string k)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0};", k));
    return Json(new { data = k}, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```

This tells WebAPI to expect this argument to be lifted from the body of the request (e.g. a JSON post payload)

Comment: Doesn't work. Yet this is with [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
            string parameters = string.Concat("k=","1");

            string url = "http://localhost:50001/Client/Index";
            using (Var wc = new WebClient()){

            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

            string result = wc.UploadString(url, parameters);

            JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);

            Console.WriteLine("Result: {0};", obj.data);               

            }`
```

Comment: `
string parameters = string.Concat("k=","1");
string url = "http://localhost:50001/Client/Index";
using (Var wc = new WebClient()){

 wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";

string result = wc.UploadString(url, parameters);

                JObject obj = JObject.Parse(result);

Console.WriteLine("Result: {0};", obj.data);               

}
`

Answer (score 1):

You need to slightly change your action to fetch posted value from Request stream:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string k)
{      
    var stream = Request.InputStream;
    string value = string.Empty;

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        value = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Result: {0};", value));
    return Json(new { data =  value}, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
}
```