# How do I modify this hitbtc code so I can use post too instead of get?

Tags: c#, php, vb.net

I managed to create hitbtc api caller

```
Protected Overrides Function getJsonPrivate(method As String, otherParameters() As Tuple(Of String, String)) As String
    Dim content = "/api/1/trading/" + method + "?nonce=" + ExchangesClass.getNonce().ToString + "&apikey=" + _apiKey1
    Dim postar = otherParameters.ToList.ConvertAll(Function(x) x.Item1 + "=" + x.Item2)
    Dim post = String.Join("&", postar) ' "id=4987469178"
    Dim sighash = computeSig(content) '"https://api.hitbtc.com/api/1/trading/cancel_order?nonce=36411402&apikey=13a2492a3f0631d657ecd510ceacc509"
    Dim url = "https://api.hitbtc.com" + content
    Dim response = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1(url, post, {Tuple.Create("X-Signature", sighash)})
    'Dim response1 = CookieAwareWebClient.downloadString1("https://api.hitbtc.com" + content + "&" + post, "", {Tuple.Create("X-Signature", sighash)})

    Return response
End Function
```

It works for their get requests. I can get balances. I can get active orders. But to cancel orders, for example, I would need post requests.

For example, doing
        _jsonResult = getJsonPrivate("balance", {})

would work just fine and I would get:

```
"{""balance"":[{""currency_code"":""1ST"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""8BT"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""ADX"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""AE"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""AEON"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""AIR"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""AMB"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},{""currency_code"":""AMP"",""cash"":""0"",""reserved"":""0""},
```

response simply result in zero.

I tried to see PhP code sample here

https://github.com/hitbtc-com/hitbtc-api/blob/master/APIv1.md#examples

And the PHP sample here

https://gist.github.com/hitbtc-com/10885873

It's still strange.

Am I supposed to computeSig based on the post requests too added to URI? With no underlying &

Has anyone C# or vb.net sample? I think it'll require only one small change to the code so I can do cancel_order method instead of just get

The content of downloadstring1 is the following. So it basically do post or get based on whether post argument is empty string or not. I think that's pretty obvious.

```
Public Shared Function downloadString1(url As String, post As String, otherHeaders As Tuple(Of String, String)()) As String
        Dim wc = New CookieAwareWebClient()
        For Each oh In otherHeaders
            wc.Headers.Add(oh.Item1, oh.Item2)
        Next

        Dim response = String.Empty

        Try
            If post = "" Then
                response = wc.DownloadString(url)
            Else
                response = wc.UploadString(url, post)
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dim a = 1
        End Try

        Return response
    End Function
```

Comment: this is not c# related

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp shows how you can use webclient to post in C#. I'm assuming VB.net would be the same (i.e. use UploadString instead of DownloadString)

Comment: It's related to C# because I don't expect anyone to know vb.net. So I need a C# sample or vb.net sample. Vb.net is best but c# is not. I already use uploadstring.

Comment: That is NOT the problem. I am asking someone familiar with hitbtc code to tell me what change of code I need to do. The function downloadstring1 already do uploadstring when post is not empty

Answer (score 0):

The only change I would need is to include the post message when computing signature

I change this

```
 Dim sighash = computeSig(content)
```

to

```
Dim sighash = computeSig(content + post)
```

Now I got this message instead

```
"{""CancelReject"":{""rejectReasonCode"":""orderNotFound""}}"
```

Which is a problem (before I just got empty string.

That would be another question.

**Update:**

Ah I should use clientOrderId rather than id or order id. Some minimum documentation.

I got this instead

?response

> `"{""ExecutionReport"":{""orderId"":""4987469178"",""latestOrderId"":""4987469178"",""clientOrderId"":""2c90f00aee8e4d21b0cd83d421297c9a"",""orderStatus"":""canceled"",""userId"":""user_319564"",""symbol"":""UGTBTC"",""side"":""buy"",""price"":""0.000018"",""quantity"":111,""type"":""limit"",""timeInForce"":""GTC"",""lastQuantity"":0,""lastPrice"":"""",""leavesQuantity"":0,""cumQuantity"":0,""averagePrice"":""0"",""created"":1509439576948,""execReportType"":""canceled"",""timestamp"":1509962441283}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have [create an account on Hitbtc](https://hitbtc.com/?ref_id=59aeac9f76e23), and [create API key](https://hitbtc.com/settings/api-keys), and add the `Place/cancel orders` Access Right, you may cancel order with a `DELETE` request (not a `POST`, not a `GET`, it is a `DELETE`):

```
DELETE /api/2/order/{clientOrderId}
```

Your request will look like this (with curl):

```
curl -X DELETE -u "ff20f250a7b3a414781d1abe11cd8cee:fb453577d11294359058a9ae13c94713" \
"https://api.hitbtc.com/api/2/order/d8574207d9e3b16a4a5511753eeef175"
```

---

From your source code, I see that you use the API V1 endpoint (/api/1/trading), but please consider that **API V1 is outdated**, and it is better to **switch to API V2**.

You may finaly refer to the [official Hitbtc API documentation](https://api.hitbtc.com/#cancelorder).

You may also double-check that the order was not already canceled ?

Regards