# Receive data from server using POST method and with a request body using WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, webclient

I am trying to receive data back from the server using POST method and the request should have a body. I am using WebClient for this and trying to get the response back in string. I know we can use HttpClient to achieve this. But I want to use WebClient for this specific instance.

I went through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401501/how-to-post-data-to-specific-url-using-webclient-in-c-sharp) and tried `UploadString` and the response gives me a 400 BAD Request.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
      wc.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");
      wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: xxxxxxx");
      wc.Headers.Add($"Authorization: Bearer {creds.APIKey.Trim()}");

      var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserRequestBody
      {
          group_id = userDetails.data.org_id
      });

      var response = wc.UploadString("https://api.xxxxx.yyy/v2/users", "POST", jsonString);
}
```

I tested the end point using Postman (with the request header having an api key and the request body in JSON) and it works fine.
[image]

I know I haven't formatted the request right. Can someone please help me.

Comment: One thing to help debug is run a tool like Fiddler. Do both requests with Postman and with your code then compare both requests Fiddler logged.

Comment: could be many things, did you try adding a Content-Type: application/json header in your webclient?

Comment: Big thanks to @SantiagoHernández. Adding `wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");` gave me a 200 OK response.

Comment: good to hear... have a good one!

Comment: You might be better off using HttpClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big Thanks to @Santiago Hernández. The issue was using `wc.Headers.Add("Accept: application/json");` in the request header. Changing it to `wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");` returned a 200 Ok response. The code modification is as follows

```
using (var wc = new WebClient())
{
      wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type: application/json");
      wc.Headers.Add("User-Agent: xxxxxxx");
      wc.Headers.Add($"Authorization: Bearer {creds.APIKey.Trim()}");

      var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new UserRequestBody
      {
          group_id = userDetails.data.org_id
      });

      var response = wc.UploadString("https://api.xxxxx.yyy/v2/users", "POST", jsonString);
}
```

`Accept` tells the server the kind of response the client will accept and `Content-type` is about the payload/content of the current request or response. Do not use `Content-type` if the request doesn't have a payload/ body.

More information about this can be found [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31212/difference-between-the-accept-and-content-type-http-headers).